# References for problems related to uniformly distributed points/ arcs on circle

Tags: probability, reference-request, euclidean-geometry

I am looking for **references** to problems related to *computing the statistical properties of uniformly randomly chosen points or arcs on the unit circle*, e.g.:

> On a unit circle, $n$ points are chosen uniformly randomly. What is the expected angular distance between nearest neighbours on the circle? What is the variance of the (angular) distance between farthest points?
>
> On a unit circle, $n$ disjoint arcs of the same length $l$ are selected at random. What is the expected (angular) distance between the nearest endpoints of consecutive arcs?

One promising example seems to be [Order Statistics](http://books.google.com/books?id=bdhzFXg6xFkC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=david+and+nagaraja+order+statistics+division+of+random+interval&source=bl&ots=OaK_l7B9-j&sig=por_GsntbxBDII72xTWISQ9Keas&hl=en&ei=urkGTevVIZTmsQOM_7HsBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by David and Nagaraja, but Google books won't let me see much of this book. I am able to find scattered references that address specific sub-problems, e.g. [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-1809.1939.tb02216.x/pdf) 1939 paper by Wesley that addresses overlapping arcs on the circle.  But I'd appreciate an exhaustive reference if there's one.

Comment: "What is the expected distance between nearest neighbours" ...................... Do you mean distance as the crow flies ... or distance travelling along the circumference of the circle?

Comment: Angular distance; corrected in post

Comment: If you have access to a library, they may be able to get you the Order Statistics book on interlibrary loan.

Comment: You may find what you need at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52493/expected-second-moment-for-random-points-on-a-circle